# Gather variables based on condition (R)

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm working through the book "R for Data Science" and would like to "gather" several variables from the dataset based on a condition (similar to select). Specifically, I want to pick just the continuous variables not the categorical ones.

How can I accomplish this without manually specifying the variables? Below does not work...

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>%
  gather(key, value, is.numeric(key))
```

Comment: may want to watch the progress of this PR https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/pull/489 or use the existing code for the time being https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/477#issuecomment-406448513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways to do this but `gather()` can take column positions as the selection argument so you can use:

```
diamonds %>%
   head(10) %>%
   gather(key, value, which(sapply(., is.numeric)))
```

Comment: Quick clarification- is the "." a placeholder for the dataframe?