# Using ggplot2 facet grid to explore large dataset with continuous and categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, frame

I have a dataset with >1000 observations belonging to either group A or group B, and ~150 categorical and continuous variables. Small version below.

```
set.seed(16)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = 1:50, group = sample(c("A", "B"), 50, replace = TRUE), length = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0, sd = 1), weight = runif(50, min=0, max=1), color = sample(c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"), 50,  replace = TRUE), size = sample(c("big", "small"), 50, replace = TRUE))
```

I would like to visually compare group A and group B across each of the variables. To start I would like to make boxplot pairs showing A and B side by side for each continuous variable, and the same using bar plots for each categorical variable. Thinking that ggplot facet_grid would be ideal for this but not sure how to specify plot type according to data tyep, also not sure how to do this without specifying each variable one-by-one.

Interested in ggplot2 help and any alternative exploration techniques.

Comment: Reshape your wide data (denoted by your numbered suffixes columns) to long format (i.e., [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)) then graphing is so much easier.

Comment: Data are cross-sectional, not longitudinal; each column is an independent measure (revised column headers to clarify). Each observation in a row, each variable in column, one entry per cell. So I think data already tidy and in long format but open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploring our data is arguably the most interesting and intellectually challenging part of our research, so I encourage you to do some more reading into this topic.
Visualisation is of course important. @Parfait has suggested to shape your data long, which makes plotting easier. Your mix of continuous and categorical data is a bit tricky. Beginners often try very hard to avoid reshaping their data - but there is no need to fret! In the contrary, you will find that most questions require a specific shape of your data, and you will in most cases not find a "one fits all" shape.
**So - the real challenge is how to shape your data before plotting.** There are obviously many ways of doing this. Below one way, which should help "automatically" reshape columns that are continuous and those that are categorical. Comments in the code.

As a side note, when loading your data into R, I'd try to avoid storing categorical data as factors, and to convert to factors only when you need it. How to do this depends how you load your data. If it is from a csv, you can for example use `read.csv('your.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

````r
library(tidyverse)

``` r
# gathering numeric columns (without ID which is numeric).
#  [I'd recommend against numeric IDs!!])
data_num <- 
  mydf %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = which(sapply(., is.numeric)), names_to = 'key', values_to =  'value')

#No need to use facet here
ggplot(data_num) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(key, value, color = group))
````

[image]

```r
# selecting categorical columns is a bit more tricky in this example, 
# because your group is also categorical. 
# One way:
# first convert all categorical columns to character, 
# then turn your "group" into factor
# then gather the character columns: 

# gathering numeric columns (without ID which is numeric).
#  [I'd recommend against numeric IDs!!])

# I use simple count() and mutate() to create a summary data frame with the proportions and geom_col, which equals geom_bar('stat = identity')
# There may be neater ways, but this is pretty straight forward 

data_cat <- 
  mydf %>% select(-ID) %>%
  mutate_if(.predicate = is.factor, .funs = as.character) %>%
  mutate(group = factor(group)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = which(sapply(., is.character)), names_to = 'key', values_to =  'value')%>%
  count(group, key, value) %>%
  group_by(group, key) %>%
  mutate(percent =  n/ sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup # I always 'ungroup' after my data manipulations, in order to avoid unexpected effects

ggplot(data_cat) +
  geom_col(aes(group, percent, fill = key)) +
  facet_grid(~ value)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Credit how to gather conditionally goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530387/7941188) from @H1

Comment: Great solution, working through it. I think geom_bar is using raw counts right? Groups A and B will be of unequal size, making it difficult to compare. Is there a way to scale or normalize using this approach? Also, why avoid storing categorical data as factors?

Comment: @marcel I might have missed your intention - what did you exactly want to explore in your categorical variables? I have assumed the occurrence (count). If they are very different, you could use a logarithmic scale instead. normalising doesn't really make sense, because you are comparing within the same variable

Comment: Factors often make things that you don't really intend, due to their hidden attributes (mainly levels). It gives better control over your data when you exactly know which variables are stored as factors and what their levels are. Letting R do this automatically when reading data can bring some surprises, especially when doing statistical analysis or plotting

Comment: The most relevant measure would simply be proportion rather than count. So if 5/10 in group A had a categorical characteristic with two possibilities (male vs female), and 20/40 in group B, the bars for groups A and B should be the same height.

Comment: This solution is the closest to what I hope to do, so accepting. I am still working on getting proportions instead of raw counts for the categorical variables. I will update when I have a complete solution.

Comment: @marcel see updated solution. There may be neater ways of creating the summary, but the herein suggested solution is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Great solution. Working through this and think I understand most of it. Last issue is that facet_grid is plotting in alphabetical order based on "value" and the various bar plots are "shuffled", (e.g.  bar plot for small is placed in the midst of bar plots for color. is there a way to order on "key" instead? Also, some of the variables are binary (e.g big vs small). Is there a way to suppress one of them (show only big, for example)? Makes sense since big and small actually plot the same information.

Comment: @marcel this is all possible of course. as the gist of the question was more how to explore large data sets, I won't take this answer further. There are plenty of threads how to sort your plots, in facets or on the x axis. (mainly a question of ordering levels). If you should not manage to find a solution based on those threads, that may warrant a follow up question - please then don't forget to link to this thread here

Answer (score 0):

What if you made the plots separately and then pieced them together in a grid?

```
set.seed(16)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = 1:50, group = sample(c("A", "B"), 50, replace = TRUE), length = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0, sd = 1), weight = runif(50, min=0, max=1), color = sample(c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"), 50,  replace = TRUE), size = sample(c("big", "small"), 50, replace = TRUE))


mydf


library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(reshape)

plot_continuous <- mydf %>%
    melt(id = "group", measure.vars = c("length", "weight")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_wrap(~variable)

plot_color <- mydf %>%
    count(group, color) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = group, y = n)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = color), position = "dodge") +
    ggtitle("Color")

plot_size <- mydf %>%
    count(group, size) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = group, y = n)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = size), position = "dodge") +
    ggtitle("Size")



plot_grid(plot_continuous, plot_color, plot_size, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: I notice that cowplot is not available for R3.3.3 and I am stuck with this version for now as I cannot update my OS. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Two options: (1) install an older version of cowplot; (2) see if you can load the gridExtra package, which gives you similar functionality. See this link: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Got this solution working by installing the previous version of cowplot. Nice package. However, it still requires one-by-one plotting. I might be able to write a function for that part.