# Optimize plotting of categorical variables using ggplot2 facet_grid - plot proportion of only one of two values for dichotomous variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

I have a large dataset with over 150 categorically and continuous variables. Each observation (row) belongs to either group A or group B. For example:

```
set.seed(16)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = 1:500, group = sample(c("A", "B", "B", "B"), 500, replace = TRUE), 
length = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 0, sd = 1), 
weight = runif(500, min=0, max=1), 
color = sample(c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"), 500,  replace = TRUE), 
size = sample(c("big", "small"), 500, replace = TRUE), 
age = sample(c("old", "young"), 500, replace = T))
```

I am working to optimize the layout of plots to visualize the relationship between group and proportional counts for the categorical variables. So far with some help from a previous post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562290/1905571) I have plots using ggplot2 facet-grid, but have encountered two problems.

Problem A: The bar plots are arranged in alphabetical order by the values (e.g. big, old, small, young) instead of grouped by the category (age: young next to old; size: big next to small, etc). Problem B: For categorical variables with only two possible values, I would like to only plot the proportion in group A vs group B for one of the values. For example, only plot the proportion of group A vs group B that are "old", since the plot of the proportion of "young" would not provide any new information. Other categorical variables like color with multiple values should have a bar plot for each possibility.

I have solved problem A by setting the factor levels in the desired plot order with " mutate(value = factor(value, levels=c("big", "small", "young", "old", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue")))" and now the plot order appears as specified, with age groups next to each other, colors next to each other, etc.

```
data_cat <- 
  mydf %>% select(-ID) %>%
  mutate_if(.predicate = is.factor, .funs = as.character) %>%
  mutate(group = factor(group)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = which(sapply(., is.character)), names_to = 'key', values_to =  'value')%>%
  count(group, key, value) %>%
  group_by(group, key) %>%
  mutate(percent =  n/ sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, levels=c("big", "small", "young", "old", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"))) %>%

ggplot(data_cat) +
  geom_col(aes(group, percent, fill = key)) +
  facet_grid(~ value)
```

I am still left with problem B, suppressing plotting of one of the two outcomes for dichotomous categorical variables. I think I have to find a way to pull out "factor levels" from each variable, then work with the subset where this value is == 2, have searched but not yet found a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the solution you were looking for with problem B? I added a filter at the end of your data management steps, removing values equal to "young" and "small", the two dichotomous cases. The plot now displays bars for "big", "old", and the 5 categories for color.

```
set.seed(16)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = 1:500, group = sample(c("A", "B", "B", "B"), 500, replace = TRUE), 
                   length = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                   weight = runif(500, min=0, max=1), 
                   color = sample(c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"), 500,  replace = TRUE), 
                   size = sample(c("big", "small"), 500, replace = TRUE), 
                   age = sample(c("old", "young"), 500, replace = T))

key <- lapply(mydf, function(x){ifelse(length(levels(x))==2, 1, 0)})
dichotomous <- names(which(key == 1))[-1]

mydf %>% select(-ID) %>%
  mutate_if(.predicate = is.factor, .funs = as.character) %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(dichotomous), .funs = function(x){ifelse(x == unique(x)[2], NA, x)}) %>%
  mutate(group = factor(group)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = which(sapply(., is.character)), names_to = 'key', values_to =  'value')%>%
  count(group, key, value) %>%
  group_by(group, key) %>%
  mutate(percent =  n/ sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value, levels=c("big", "small", "young", "old", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"))) %>%
  na.omit() -> data_cat

ggplot(data_cat) +
  geom_col(aes(group, percent, fill = key)) +
  facet_grid(~ value)
```

Comment: This will do it "manually" for this example, but I will eventually have > 150 variables, and would like to find a solution that tracks (finds) all bivariate categorical variables.

Comment: Hi Marcel, I edited my original answer to make this automated. It may seem a bit sloppy, which I apologize for, but in the mutate_at line, I set the second "level" or "unique value" of each dichotomous variable as NA, then simply remove all missing rows at the end. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, that did it.